# Can media corportation take away my domain name?

Tags: domains, legal, branding, money, trademark

Recently i've noticed that there is actually free cool domain name, let's say 'googleinsider.com`. Buy this domain is my dream and for some money (not so small well) i can buy this domain.

And i will use it for website then. Website is about somewhat connected with real Google. But i will not write there anything bad.

However, i understand, that if i use this domain for my project, Google will try to take it away from me, as it is a trademark or brand name. Is that possible? Is it really easy (is there are any examples of domains returned by such companies)?

Comment: Sorry but there is already a vast amount of [domain trademark infringement related questions](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=domain+trademark) on Pro Webmasters. To avoid further disappointment please ensure you visit our help centre before posting.

Comment: @SimonHayter read again, i am asking for any real stories. Remove duplicate flag, please.

Comment: Sorry but that would mean the question would become too board, likely opinionated and would likely extend into extended discussion, all of which are are considered closure reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big legal question is whether visitors to your website will confuse you with the corporate Google. If you set up a math website that talked about 10^100 and all its implications, you'd likely be fine (especially if you included a "I have nothing to do with Google™" statement on every page). If you set up a "I work for Google, and here's all the inside dirt!" then you wouldn't.

However, whether or not you'd be in the right is less important than whether Google decides to come after you. Remember [Jeph Jacques](http://questionablecontent.net)'s website [walmart.horse](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2015/05/walmart-horse-is-put-out-to-pasture-after-retailer-starts-domain-dispute/)? If he had the will (and the legal budget) he probably could have kept it, but in the end it just wasn't worth the trouble.

So, if you're thinking about tweaking Google, consider how you'd handle the possible results. It may not be worth the trouble.